# 301 Redirect Not Working - Appending Path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Can someone please advise why the following isn't working?

```
Redirect 301 /foo/bar/test/ https://www.example.com
```

It's redirecting to `https://www.example.com/bar/test/` (notice the `/foo/` has been removed?) instead of simply `https://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Redirect 301 /foo/bar/test/ https://www.example.com`

I think what you are seeing is a cached response, since there is no way the above directive could produce the stated result.

However, since you only want to redirect to the root domain, a `Redirect` is not the correct directive for the job. `Redirect` is prefix matching and will copy path segments after the match onto the target URL.

So, for example, given the above directive and a request for `/foo/bar/test/baz`, you would be redirected to `https://www.example.combaz/` - note the additional `baz/` on the URL (and the missing slash after the domain name - that is another problem, caused by the trailing slash on your URL-path `/foo/bar/test/`. If you needed the trailing slash then you would need to add the trailing slash to the target as well).

Try `RedirectMatch` insead:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/foo/bar/test/$ https://www.example.com
```

Change the 302 to a 301 when you are satisfied it is working OK. (301 redirects are cached by the browser, so can make testing troublesome.)

`RedirectMatch` uses regex instead of simple prefix matching. Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Answer (score 0):

Try just "foo/bar/test/" instead of "/foo/bar/test/"

Comment: In a mod_alias `Redirect` the URL-path is a path beginning with a slash (root-relative), so removing the slash is not going to help.